# Entries to find a positive definite matrix as solution of Lyapunov equation.

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

Given the [Lyapunov equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_equation) below:

$AX + XA^T + B = 0$ with $B=bb^T$

**I just want to simulate A $\in \mathcal{M}_{p,p}(\mathbb{R})$ and b $\in \mathbb{R}^{p}$ to find X, solution definite positive.**

In theory, having $A$ definite negative and $B$ positive semi definite (by definition : $bb^T$ is positive semi definite) should ensure that $X$ is positive definite.

But it is not the case in practice, so what are the sufficient conditions?
Or maybe it is a computational issue: when I check the eigenvalues of $bb^T$, some are negative (but $10^{-11}$ negative).

Comment: I am also interessed by articles or lessons able to give me the anwer of my problem.

Comment: Any hint for me?